# Does moksha happen after death or in same life according to Nyaya darshan?

Tags: moksha, shad-darshana, nyaya, nyaya-sutra

I'm studying Nyaya Darshan. According to Nyaya Sutra 1.2, suffering is caused by birth and birth is caused by mithyajnana (ignorance).

> दुःखजन्मप्रवृत्तिदोषमिथ्याज्ञानानाम् उत्तरोत्तरापाये तदनन्तरा पायात् अपवर्गः

It further says that ignorance is removed by tatvajnana (true knowledge) then moksha happens which is freedom from all sufferings and samsar. My question is does that moksha happen after death or at the moment when tattvajnana (true knowledge) is grasped acording to Nyaya Darshan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, Nyāyadarśana [uses](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-sutras-study/d/doc628668.html) the word *apavarga* (अपवर्ग), for Mokṣa, which literally means fulfillment or completion. The other word, *niḥśreyas* (निःश्रेयस) also occurs as alternative to Mokṣa, which means most excellent or supreme good.

The final release (mokṣa) is said to be attained post death.

> Quoting the Satish Chandra Vidyabhushan's commentary on [Nyaya Sutra
> 1.1.22](https://archive.org/details/NyayaSutra/page/n31/mode/1up?view=theater)
>
> ॥ तदत्यन्तविमोक्षः अपवर्गः ॥
>
> > 22. Release is the absolute deliverance from Pain.
>
> Commentary:-
>
> > A soul which is no longer subject to transmigration is freed from all
> > pains. Transmigration, which consists in the soul's leaving one body
> > and taking another, is the cause of its undergoing pleasure and pain.
> > **The soul attains release as soon as there is an end of the body, and, con- sequently, of pleasure and pain.** Those are mistaken who
> > maintain that release enables the soul not only to get rid of all
> > pains but also to attain eternal pleasure, for pleasure is as
> > impermanent as pain and the body.

Further,

> [Nyaya Sutra 4.2.45](https://archive.org/details/NyayaSutra/page/n161/mode/1up?view=theater)
>
> ॥ तदभावश्चापवर्गे ॥
>
> > 45. And there's absence if body in our release.
>
> Commentary
>
> > Our merits and demerits having already been exhausted, we cannot get a
> > body after we have attained release. Release is the perfect freedom
> > from all sufferings : it consists in complete destruction of all the
> > seats and seeds of sufferings

So, as per the Nyaya Darshana, the state of Jivanmukti may exist (free from the bondages of the Maya), but the final salvation (Mokṣa - निःश्रेयस/अपवर्ग) is only realised post the destruction of the body.

Comment: What does release, birth and death mean according to nyaya shastra? Release could also mean realizing that Atman is never associated with body. Death could also mean the death of the notion "I am body or body is mine" which is मिथ्याज्ञान. My interpretation makes sense because that's the only way that मिथ्याज्ञान can give rise to birth. Otherwise saying that the false notion "I am body" REALLY results in birth doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Disassociation of the Soul-body-mind complex must verily occur in the life through various practices like Yoga, etc. But, It's death of the gross body, which is said to be the final pinnacle point of Moksha, known as apavarga/nihshreyas in the Nyaya system. @Lokesh . That's my understanding out of it. :)

Comment: @Vivikta I am interested in Nyaya Darshana and you seem to know a lot about it. However, I also love the Bhagavad Gita and Vaishnavism. How can I reconcile the two and believe in both? Are their any Vaishnava Nyaya scholars or Nyaya commentaries on the Bhagavad Gita?